# -Werror causes compiler to stop on #warning. What can I do to prevent this?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

First off, I **want** it to stop on warnings.   But I also want to print out some informative messages (like "Come back and implement this!").

Unfortunately, my compiler doesn't support `#info`, `#message`, `#pragma message()`, etc.

I know there's `-Wno-error=<something>`, but my google-foo is weak, and I can't seem to find out the `<something>` for `#warning`.  I've tried `-Wno-error=warning`, and that just says "there's no `-Wwarning`".  Same with "`warn`".

Any suggestions?

For what its worth, I'm using the Tensilica [Xtensa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensilica) compiler, xt-xcc, which appears to be a GNU derivative, or at least uses the GNU front end.  It's version 8.0.0.

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: Since you say it's a GNU derivative: the `-fdiagnostics-show-option` option for gcc tells it to tell you what option controls each warning that occurs. Maybe xt-xcc has that?

Comment: The other option would be (very ugly) to individually turn all other warnings into errors.

Comment: I tried -fdiagnostics-show-option, and nothing extra was printed out, so that seems to be a bit of a dead end.  I'm not sure which version of GCC it spawns from (that isnt' reported in its own version info).  And yeah, I'm not looking forward to turning warnings into errors one at a time.

Comment: Retagged to "embedded" because you indicated below that this was an embedded project.

Comment: @JXG: Except that the question is not specific to 'embedded' and is generally applicable to GCC.  Not sure that it justifies the embedded tag.

Comment: `-Wno-error=cpp` works with my `gcc` version 4.6.1 (see my answer). The newer gcc is graceful in naming the category name for the warning... :-)

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with the Tensilica Xtensa compiler (`xt-xcc`), but with standard GCC you can use

```
  #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wcpp"
```

to make `#warning` a matter of simple warning (not an error because of `-Werror`). To make the effect temporary, you can embrace this `#pragma` and the `#warning` between `#pragma GCC diagnostic push` and `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop`.

When I compile a file containing the following

```
    #pragma GCC diagnostic push
    #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wcpp"
    #warning one
    #pragma GCC diagnostic pop

    #warning two
```

with `-Werror` using GCC 4.6.1 (command `gcc -c -Werror warning-test.c`), I get the following output:

````
```lang-none
warning-test.c:3:2: warning: #warning one [-Wcpp]
warning-test.c:6:2: error: #warning two [-Werror=cpp]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```
````

When I remove the second `#warning`, the compilation is not interrupted by an error.

You can also replace your `-Werror` compiler options with `-Werror -Wno-error=cpp`. I am not aware what other effects the `cpp` category of warnings include (and you might have a legitimate `#warning` in some other place that you want to catch as error), so temporarily disabling the error for a specific `#warning` and restoring the settings immediately after seems more accurate method of meeting your requirements.

Using GCC versions 4.8.4 and 4.9.2 gives pretty much the same behavior (only the source line is printed out additionally). But using GCC version 5.0.1 (prerelease version included in [Ubuntu 15.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_15.04_.28Vivid_Vervet.29) (Vivid Vervet)) will give two warnings unless option `-Werror=cpp` is included as well. So it seems that `-Werror` with a newer GCC does not anymore imply `-Werror=cpp` like before and it needs to be provided separately if desired.

Comment: Upvoted, but the above snippet still fails for me (using gcc 4.8.4)

Comment: @M2X - fails how? You need to include option `-c` (compile only); otherwise `gcc` tries to link and it will fail due to missing function `main()` I guess. I tested with `gcc` 4.8.4 and 4.9.2 and nothing essentially changed since I originally wrote this answer. However using gcc 5.0 `-Werror` does not imply `-Werror=cpp` any more.

Comment: @FooF I should've been more clear. I wasn't talking about your sample snippet (with `main`) above. I'm working in a large project that has `-Werror` on. I'm trying to get gcc to ignore some `#warning`s in some of the Qt headers. When I added `#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wcpp"` before including those headers, I still get an error (instead of a warning) when the compiler reaches that `#warning` line... Any thoughts?

Comment: @M2X - Does your `gcc` work like described above for this sniplet? I do not have time to investigate your problem, but did you try if maybe (pushded or all) `#pragma GCC diagnostic` things are reset during #include somehow? Otherwise maybe you could just consider adding `-Eno-error=cpp` to your compiler flags if you do not want to stop when encountering other `#warning`s are something that should not be there. Of course you could check GCC documentation too for more information about those `#pragma` thingelings.

Answer (score 2):

Ten years later, the proper way to issue warnings and avoid these additional messages/errors from -Wpedantic is to use `#pragma message`. GCC supports this syntax since at least [GCC 4.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html), and Clang since at least [Clang 6](https://prereleases.llvm.org/6.0.0/rc2/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas).

Modern versions of these compilers even support `#pragma GCC error "message"` and `#pragma GCC warning "message"` ([GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html), already supported in Clang 6).

Comment: I'm finding `#pragma GCC warning "message"` is still triggering an error.

Comment: Maybe you are passing `-Werror`.  And since you don't specify the GCC version, it's hard to know what problem you have.

Comment: I am passing `-Werror`, that's what the original question was about.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

```
#warning "Come back and implement this"
#warning "Do not do that!"
#warning "Must fix this before release"
```

Normally, the compiler will include the argument(s) to - or material after - `#warning` in the error or warning message.

And, normally, if the compiler detects something that warrants a warning, it reports it fairly clearly.

---

Given the requirements, I think the only way to deal with this is to protect the `#warning` directives...

```
#ifdef DO_WARNINGS
#warning "Some warning"
#endif /* DO_WARNINGS */
```

Most of the time, you compile without `-DDO_WARNINGS`; when you need to check on the `#warning` warnings (with `-Werror`), then you include `-DDO_WARNINGS` after all, accepting that the compilation will fail.  Remember that `make -k` will do as much as possible even in the presence of individual compilation errors.

---

Section 5.52.9 of the GCC 4.4.1 manual says (in part):

> #### 5.52.9 Diagnostic Pragmas
>
> GCC allows the user to selectively enable or disable certain types of diagnostics, and change
>   the kind of the diagnostic. For example, a project’s policy might require that all sources
>   compile with ‘-Werror’ but certain files might have exceptions allowing specific types of
>   warnings. Or, a project might selectively enable diagnostics and treat them as errors depending
>   on which preprocessor macros are defined.
>
> ```
> #pragma GCC diagnostic kind option
> ```
>
> Modifies the disposition of a diagnostic. Note that not all diagnostics are modifiable;
>   at the moment only warnings (normally controlled by ‘-W...’) can be
>   controlled, and not all of them. Use ‘-fdiagnostics-show-option’ to determine
>   which diagnostics are controllable and which option controls them.
>   kind is ‘error’ to treat this diagnostic as an error, ‘warning’ to treat it like
>   a warning (even if ‘-Werror’ is in effect), or ‘ignored’ if the diagnostic is to
>   be ignored. option is a double quoted string which matches the command line
>   option.
>
> ```
> #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wformat"
> #pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wformat"
> #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat"
> ```
>
> Note that these pragmas override any command line options. Also, while it
>   is syntactically valid to put these pragmas anywhere in your sources, the only
>   supported location for them is before any data or functions are defined. Doing
>   otherwise may result in unpredictable results depending on how the optimizer
>   manages your sources. If the same option is listed multiple times, the last
>   one specified is the one that is in effect. This pragma is not intended to be a
>   general purpose replacement for command line options, but for implementing
>   strict control over project policies.
>
> GCC also offers a simple mechanism for printing messages during compilation.
>
> ```
> #pragma message string
> ```
>
> Prints string as a compiler message on compilation. The message is informational
>   only, and is neither a compilation warning nor an error.
>
> ```
> #pragma message "Compiling " __FILE__ "..."
> ```
>
> string may be parenthesized, and is printed with location information.

I'm not sure whether you feel like editing your `#warning` lines into `#pragma message` lines.  It would get you around the problem - and is only worse than adding conditional compilation around the `#warning` in that `#pragma message` might be supported by fewer compilers.  It depends on what your portability requirements are.

Comment: The crux of the problem is that #warning causes compilation to stop when -Werror is on the command line, and I don't know how to override that beyond removing -Werror, which is not an option.

Comment: You want warnings to be errors except when they're supposed to be warnings after all?  Tricky...if not contradictory.

Comment: Well, I want warnings to be errors, except for this one (or ones of this class). I just don't know what to pass to -Wno-error=???? to not treat #warning as an error.  That or I'd like the tools to offer #message, or  #pragma message() or something similar.

Comment: I don't think that is possible with the current GCC code base.  `-Werror` makes any warning, from any source, into an error (as you are all too aware), and there isn't a way to avoid that AFAIK.  You're going to have to do without your #warnings, or protect them with `#ifdef DO_WARNINGS / #warning "Some warning" / #endif`

Comment: -Wno-error=implicit, for example, makes 'implicit function calls' warnings not be treated as errors even in the presence of -Werror.   I was hoping the collective knowledge of the internet would know the magical incantation that would describe the class of warnings that are "#warning", so I could turn that off similar to how other classes of warnings could be.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no answer for my specific toolchain, or so says the engineers at Tensilica.  They don't support #message, or #pragma message(), or know of how to suppress #warning as error in the presence of [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror).

The GCC toolchain allows the use of -Wno-error=[code] to say "this warning is *not* an error", but I haven't found a list that corresponds #warning to any code this would take (or even a list of codes this could be).

I may try to find the time to delve into the standard GCC command lines and pre-processor source code to try to find a list of what -Wno-error= can be equal to, or whether or not there's a -Werror= code that corresponds to #warning.

Answer (score 1):

Given that #warning is presumably processed by the pre-processor, you could run the pre-processor separately without -Werror, then run the compiler with pre-processing inhibited on the pro-processor output.

To do this run the .c file through the preprocessor with all the normal options except -Werror, and generate the output as a .i file (.ii for C++).  The compiler recognises these files as *not to be pre-processed* so you can compile them with -Werror, and assuming that the pre-processor drops the #warning and it is not processed by the compiler itself, this may resolve your problem.

I have not tested this; when I encountered the same problem I just chose to live with it and not use -Werror.  The solution seemed more complex than the problem!

Comment: I've chosen the same route. The goal for me is not to have zero warnings. The goal is to only have warnings generated by the #warning-directive, and few enough that you don't have to scroll to read them all. This works in a +100KLOC sized commercial project with four-five guys collaborating. Embedded real-time code written in C.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports it, you can try using the [`constructor` function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconstructor_007d-function-attribute-2403) to define a function that runs at program start (before `main`) that prints out a message to stdout:

```
#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) TOKENPASTE2(x, y)
#define TOKENPASTE2(x, y) x ## y
#define WARNING(message) \
  static void TOKENPASTE(_print_warning, __LINE__)() __attribute__((constructor)); \
  static void TOKENPASTE(_print_warning, __LINE__)() \
  { \
    puts(message); \
  }

WARNING("fix this before ship")  // prints out a message at runtime before main
```

This causes a message to be printed out at runtime instead of compile-time, which is almost as good, especially if you have no other options.  The only restriction is that you have to use this at global scope outside of a function definition.

Comment: This is an embedded project, which doesn't have a console, or a screen.

Answer (score 0):

`-Wno-error=#warnings` seem to work with recent clangs (tested 14..17)

G++ (11 & 12) does not support the equivalent and suggest using `--no-warnings` - which is not what you want.

The only issue might be to get the hash digested by your build tool, so it goes to the compiler...