# Have the Arduino IDE set compiler warnings to error

Tags: arduino, compiler-construction, command-line-arguments

Is there a way to set the compiler warnings to be interpreted as an error in the Arduino IDE?
Or any generic way to set GCC compiler options?

I have looked at the *~/.arduino/preferences.txt* file, but I found nothing that indicates fine-tuned control. I also looked if I could set GCC options via environment variables, but I did not find anything.

I don't want to have verbose compiler output (which you can specify using the IDE) that is way too much distracting non-essential information, and I don't want to waste my time on reading through it.

I want for a compilation to stop on a warning, so code can be cleaned up. My preference would be to be able to set `-Werror=` options, but a generic `-Werror` will do for the small code size of `.ino` projects.

Addendum:

Based on the suggestion in the selected answer, I implemented an `avr-g++` script and put that in the path before the normal `avr-g++`. For that I changed the Arduino command as follows:

```
-export PATH="${APPDIR}/java/bin:${PATH}"
+export ORGPATH="${APPDIR}/java/bin:${PATH}"
+export PATH="${APPDIR}/extra:${ORGPATH}"
```

And in the new directory `extra` in the APPSDIR (where the Arduino command is located), I have
an `avr-g++` which is a Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import subprocess

werr = '-Werror'
wall = '-Wall'

cmd = ['avr-g++'] + sys.argv[1:]
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['ORGPATH']
fname = sys.argv[-2][:]
if cmd[-2].startswith('/tmp'):
    #print fname, list(fname) # this looks strange
    for i, c in enumerate(cmd):
        if c == '-w':
            cmd[i] = wall
            break
    cmd.insert(1, werr)
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

So you replace the first command with the original compiler name and reset the environment used to exclude the `extra` directory.

The `fname` is actually strange. If you print it, it is only `abc.cpp`, but its length is much larger and it actually starts with `/tmp`. So I check for that to decide whether to add/update the compile options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are on Linux. Arduino is a script, so you can set PATH in the script to include a directory at the beginning to a directory containing a program, *avr-g++*. Then the Java stuff should take the compiler from there, should it not?

That program then calls the normal */usr/bin/avr-g++* with the extra options.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like an idea. I hope the java stuff does not have the search paths for avr-g++ hard coded ( I would not wonder if it did).

Comment: You can actually do this. I found that by default the setting is -w, which is kind of stupid IMHO as if the problem goes away when you just ignore it. So the -Werror only works when prefrences are set to compile verbosily (otherwise the -w suppresses it). Now I need to implement a way to select -Werror for just my .ino file for the libraries (GSM, SoftSerial) have lots of errors that I am not going to be able to address right now.

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to compile your sketches from the command line. Take a look at this [makefile](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/uploads/Learning/Makefile).

Comment: Thanks I have used that before, but the (only?) nice thing about using the IDE is that is kills the debug serial monitor before uploading. Maybe I should just get an external serial monitor and kill that from within the makefile.

Comment: Seems the Makefile is not compatible with the 1.0 version of the IDE anymore.