# Arduino double command

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to find a way for my Arduino to recognize some of the commands I'm attempting to send over serial (via Raspberry Pi)

I'm come as far as to detect 2 commands, but I'm stuck at my last.

To give a little bit more detail, I have my fingerprint scanner (GT-511C3) connected, and the library installed that will make it work.

That said, with the first 2 commands consist the verifying of fingerprints to ID (which works great) and the enrolling of fingerprints to new ID's (also work great) these parts of the script are triggered by the respective ASCII code "0" and "1".

My last, and problematic command "2" to remove an ID, is where I'm seeking help with.

Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```
if(ser == '2'){
    while(val2 == 0){  
        char val3 = 0;
        delay(10);
        Serial.println("Type the ID to be deleted");
        delay(2500);
        fps.DeleteID(Serial.read());
        val3 == Serial.read();
        delay(10);
        Serial.println("Deleted ID:");
        Serial.print(val3);
        delay(10);
        val2 = 1;
    }    
}
```

I'm attempting to send the ASCII code "2" over Raspberry Pi through serial to the Arduino, followed by the ID that needs to be removed. It triggers after the command "2" is send, but refuses to read the ID and as such, I'm unable to finish it.

Any help or insight would really be appreciated.

Comment: `val3 == Serial.read();` is a NOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val3 == Serial.read();` should be `val3 = Serial.read();`. You have an extra `=` which turns it into a useless comparison.

Comment: Thank you for catching that! Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem...

Comment: Do you get any specific errors? You could follow the advice in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29095593/2830652 to add extra warning flags to your compiler which will catch small typos and issues like this one in the future.