# Unable to read status of digital pin

Tags: loops, arduino

**EXPLANATION**

The function of the code I include below is to send the 'a' value through SS and also print its value. The code is compiled without errors, but it doesn't accomplish its purpose.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
I connected the pin 7 to the 5v of the Arduino.

**CODE**

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial test (3,2);  
int i=0;

void send(){
    test.write(i);
    Serial.print(i);
    i++;
    delay(1000);
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(1200);
    test.begin(1200);
    pinMode(7,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    if ( digitalRead(7) == HIGH ) {
        void send();
    }
}
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS** 
Send 'i' value using the serial library and print the result.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile.  Check your compile warnings and errors.  'void send();' is not an executable statement.  Your braces don't even match.

Comment: @TomServo compile without errors 

Comment: Warnings are default disabled in the Arduino IDE (it is totally asinine). Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7892304/8548828) to enable **all** warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void send();`

this is not the proper way of calling a function.
Let me quickly fix the code here for you.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial test (3,2);  
int a=0;

void send(){
 test.write(a);
 Serial.println(a);
 a++;
 delay(1000);
}

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(1200);
 test.begin(1200);
 pinMode(7,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
 if ( digitalRead(7) == HIGH ) {
  send();
 }

}
```

try it like this!

Comment: thanks! can u explain why and what happens with the things declared outside void setup and void loop?

Comment: @JuanCA It is not specific to `setup` and `loop` functions. You might need to look at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c/