# How to disable GCC warning about the #warning directive being a GCC extension?

Tags: gcc, warnings, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

When using the `#warning` directive, rather than one warning I get two - the one I generate, plus an additional
`warning: #warning is a GCC extension [enabled by default]`.

I can suppress the #warning directive's result itself, with `-Wno-cpp`, but that's the opposite of what I want.

I can work around this by instead using `#pragma message()` but that seems to render the #warning directive rather pointless - is there no way to suppress this warning warning?

Comment: What are the options you are passing to GCC?

Comment: It was `-g -static -static-libgcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-vla -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wmissing-declarations -march=native -fexceptions -fexpensive-optimizations -flto -O3 -std=c++1y -fsanitize=address` in this case - see my answer below, i realised it was the -pedantic option that was responsible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, it seems the `-pedantic` option enables this warning, and there does not seem to be a specific override for it, as there is with most other GCC warnings.  Removing `-pedantic` gets rid of the warning about a warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#warning "no warning here!"
#endif
```

will compile with or without gcc, even with  `-pedantic`, but it will still give the warning, (and fail if warnings are escalated to errors).

UPDATE:
According to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4371718/905902), there is no clean solution to selectively disable the warnings about the gnu-specific #pragma s

Comment: Certainly it'll compile, in any case, but that doesn't do anything to get rid of the warning:  `warning: #warning is a GCC extension [enabled by default]`

Comment: Yes, I just realized that myself. Desparately looking for a pragma to swich the damn thing off. ( adding `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"` does not seem to work. )

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the following should work. With that you can suppress/ignore the gcc warnings.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcpp"

...

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Although this is a good idea, i'm afraid this won't work with the -pedantic warnings.  See test code here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=53358c525169b7c2750ed1eb09dff702-0f11904895a20602a6e5ca9f4b5b0039